# how to show that the set where Real part of an analytic function vanish contains arcs

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Consider a function $f$ given by $f(z)=z^3g(z)$, where $g(0)\neq 0$. Then clearly $z=0$ is a zero of function $f$ of multiplicity $3$. Let $A$ be the set given by $\{z: \Re f=0\}$.

How do i show that $A$ contains $3$ smooth arcs. When $g$ is a constant map, i am able to get this. But how to do it when $g$ is not a constant map?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $f$ has a zero of order $n$ at $a$, then $f$ is $n$-to-1 on all sufficiently small neighborhoods of $a$.

Comment: can you please explain how to proceed once we see this is $n$ to $1$ on sufficiently small neighborhoods of $a$.

Comment: @user1123 The image contains 0, and so a neighborhood of 0 by analyticity, and so a portion of the imaginary axis. Pulling back a small enough such neighborhood to a neighborhood of $z=0$ we get exactly three smooth copies of that portion of the imaginary axis. Separated by angles of $2\pi/3$, in fact.

Comment: it seems to work, but how to do it explicitly. i tried it, but couldnt do it explicitly.

Comment: @user1123 What do you mean by explicit? You can't expect a complete formula for the arcs in general. If you don't understand where the hint comes from, then I suggest refreshing yourself on the argument principle.